# XSLT2 context for for-each-group attributes

Tags: xslt-2.0

I am fairly experienced with XSLT1, and have been starting to work with XSLT2.  Most of the changes are easy enough to understand, but I am having a little trouble understanding how the attributes on a for-each-group element are evaluated in xslt2.  Suppose that I have the following input document

```
<root>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <notanitem>abc</notanitem>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>7</item>
</root>
```

The following stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <result>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="root/item" group-by="(position() - 1) idiv 3">
                <row>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <cell><xsl:value-of select="."/></cell>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </row>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

groups the *item*s into *row*s with 3 *cell*s each, producing

```
<result>
    <row>
        <cell>1</cell>
        <cell>2</cell>
        <cell>3</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>4</cell>
        <cell>5</cell>
        <cell>6</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>7</cell>
    </row>
</result>
```

Thus only the *item* elements are being counted in assigning positions.

Now, if I change the for-each-group to use `group-starting-with="*[position() mod 3 = 1]"`.  I get items 1, 2, and 3 in the first row; items 4 and 5 in the second row; and items 6 and 7 in the third row (so the *notanitem* element is being counted in assigning positions).

It seems that in the first case, the position function is evaluated only on the items, yet in the second case, the position function is evaluated on the entire document (or the children under the root element).

Is this the case?  Is the `group-by` evaluation limited **only** to the items that actually are selected by the for-each-group construct, but the `group-starting-with` evaluation is based on the entire subtree that those elements are in (including unselected elements)?  What is the context that those two attributes are evaluated in?

I feel that I almost have the right idea of how these work, but this is confusing me as I can't quite see the right way to interpret this in the specification, and other questions that I have looked at don't seem to be asking or answering about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `group-by` is an expression computing grouping keys, the `group-starting-with` however is a pattern (you know from XSLT 1.0 as the `match` attribute of `xsl:template` or of `xsl:key`).

If you use `group-starting-with="item[position() mod 3 = 1]"` instead, then you can see the same result as with your `group-by`.

As for the evaluation of the `group-by`, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping which says

> When calculating grouping keys for an item in the population, the
>   expression contained in the group-by or group-adjacent attribute is
>   evaluated with that item as the context item, with its position in
>   population order as the context position, and with the size of the
>   population as the context size. The resulting sequence is atomized,
>   and each atomic value in the atomized sequence acts as a grouping key
>   for that item in the population.

The `population` https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#dt-population is defined as the sequence selected by the `for-each-group select="expression"`:

> [Definition: The sequence of items to be grouped, which is referred to
>   as the population, is determined by evaluating the XPath expression
>   contained in the select attribute.]

As for the `position()` call inside the pattern of your `group-starting-with`, you first need to look at the pattern and obviously `*` matches all elements and not only `item` elements.